# Can you graph multiple y points for the same x coordinate?

Tags: r, time, graph, plot, hour

I have a dataframe named June, with a column named Hour containing; 0:00, 0:15, 0:30, 0:45, 1:00, 1:15, up until 23:45 and then repeating for 30 days. Another column called Diff_H1H2 contains numeric data such as; 0.0017, 0.0067, -0.019,-0.24 and so on.

I just want to plot the data and tried.

```
plot(June$Hour, June$Diff_H1H2)
```

This is the error msg.

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Also these are the classes:

```
> class(June$Hour)
[1] "character"
> class(June$Diff_H1H2)
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Is `June$Hour` formatted as character? That would give the error you're getting. Format `June$Hour` in date/time format and then you'll be able to plot it.

Comment: You'll make it easier for people to help you if you post a sample of your data so that others can come up with a solution in the context of your specific problem. For example, to post 20 randomly selected rows of your data, paste of the output of `dput(June[sample(1:nrow(June),20),])` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I made up some dummy data for you:

```
Hour <- rep(c('0:15', '0:30', '0:45'), 3)
Hour <- as.numeric(gsub(':', '', Hour))
Diff_H1H2 <- runif(9, min = 0, max = 1)
June <- data.frame(Hour, Diff_H1H2)

plot(June$Hour, June$Diff_H1H2, xaxp = c(15, 45, 2))
```

[image: numeric image]

To convert your data to date/time format you can do the follow instead of the as.numeric row about:

```
Hour <- paste0("2010-01-01", " ", Hour, ":00")
Hour <- as.POSIXct(Hour)
```

Which when run with the other few lines of code results in the following image:

[image: time image]